# From SQL query to JPA query

Tags: java, jpa

How I transform this into a jpa/jpl query? Will it be possible/cleaner to write it using **CriteriaQuery**?

```
select vc.category_id, count(distinct vc.something_id)
from 
  place p, something_category vc, something_poi vp, something v left join something_external_provider vep on vep.something_id=v.id
and (vep.provider is null or (vep.provider = 'EULA' and vep.lastretrieveddate >= now()-interval 1 day))
where p.id=vp.place_id and 
v.id=vc.something_id and
v.id=vp.something_id and 
v.isprivate=0 and 
(v.is_sponsored is null OR v.is_sponsored=0) and 
v.status in (1,11,31) and 
vp.status in (1,2) and 
(EXISTS (select id from something_app where something_id=v.id and app_id=1) OR NOT EXISTS (select id from something_app where something_id=v.id)) and 
v.enddate>now() and 
(country='US' and type='country,political')
group by vc.category_id;
```

here's what I came out with so far

```
private static final String QUERY = "SELECT vc.category, COUNT(DISTINCT vc.something) "
        + "FROM Place p, SomethingCategory vc, SomethingPoi vp, Something v LEFT JOIN SomethingExternalProvider vep ON vep.something=v AND "
        + "(vep.provider IS null or (vep.provider in ( :providers ) and vep.lastretrieveddate >= (now() - INTERVAL 1 DAY))) "
        + "WHERE p=vp.place AND v=vc.something AND v=vp.something AND v.isprivate=0 AND "
        + "(v.isSponsored is null OR v.isSponsored=0) AND v.status IN (?,?,?)) AND vp.status IN (1,2) and "
        + "(EXISTS (SELECT vga.id FROM SomethingApp vga WHERE something = v AND app = :app) OR NOT EXISTS (SELECT vga.id FROM SomethingApp vga WHERE something=v)) AND "
        + "v.enddate>now() AND (country = :country AND type='country, political') " + "GROUP BY vc.category";
```

and then

```
    Query query = entityManager.createQuery(QUERY).setParameter("providers", string)
        .setParameter("app", app).setParameter("US", country)
        .setParameter(1, SomethingStatusType.ACTIVE.getType())
        .setParameter(2, SomethingStatusType.EXTERNAL.getType());
```

Comment: +1 for criteria for such complex queries.

Comment: Please show us that you have made some effort at trying to do this yourself. Nobody here will be very willing to do your work for you. If you have tried something and it doesn't work, show us and we can help you solve specific problems.

Comment: i'm thinking the issue might be on the fact that i'm mixing `setParameter(String` with `setParameter(int`

Comment: Just for the record, you could use joins instead of Descartes multiplication in your initial query.

Comment: i was only able to make it work the sql way. i'm still trying to understand how CriteriaQuery would work in this particular case